# Material UI tabs - TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, tabs, material-ui

I'm trying to get Material UI tabs working, I have this component:

```
const ItemssOverview = ({ details }) => {
    if (details && details.items) {
        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar position="static" color="default">
                    <Tabs
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        indicatorColor="primary"
                        textColor="primary"
                        scrollable
                        scrollButtons="auto"
                    >
                        {
                            details.items.map(item => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={item.id}>
                                        <Tab label={item.Name} />
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </Tabs>
                </AppBar>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (<div>&nbsp;</div>);
};
```

I want to dynamically generate the amount of tabs, best on the list of detail items. But, using the above code I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

```
capitalizeFirstLetter
C:/Development/Repos/IP/operations-mo-dashboard/src/mo-dashboard/node_modules/material-ui/utils/helpers.js:30
  27 | function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  28 |   process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? (0, _warning2.default)(typeof string === 'string', 'Material-UI: capitalizeFirstLetter(string) expects a string argument.') : void 0;
  29 | 
> 30 |   return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  31 | } //  weak
  32 | 
  33 | function contains(obj, pred) {
```

I think it's because `<Tabs/>` expect to see a `<Tab/>` tag, not a div, but I need that div to put the map key on.

> Any suggestions on how to get it work?

PS: For more info on tabs, see [here](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tabs/).

Comment: You can put key on the <Tab /> itself.

Comment: Is it possible `item.Name` is undefined here? I could see material-ui trying to capitalize the `label` passed through and encountering this error then. What happens if you change it to `label={item.Name || ''}`?

Comment: @PavelStaselun: That was so easy ... could you please repeat your response as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In short - you specify "key" prop on a "Tab" itself.

[Meterial-UI "spreads"](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/86b40ae4883e95d6139e9e5d59c0e14aa022ce3a/src/Tabs/Tab.js#L129) the "other" props to the root.

Instead of:

```
<div key={item.id}>
  <Tab label={item.Name} />
</div>
```

Do:

```
<Tab key={item.id} label={item.Name} />
```

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a working sample please?